# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConnectorUserAgentProvider

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Below is the code i was using to import a bigquery table to my PySpark cluster(dataproc) and then run fp-growth algorithm on it. But, today when i ran the same code it was throwing an error. It returns the schema of the imported df with .printSchema() but when i try to run .show() or .fit(), it throws the below error.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Jupyter BigQuery Storage').config('spark.jars','gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar').getOrCreate()
```

```
table = "project_name.dataset_name.test_table"
df = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("table",table).load()
df.printSchema()


df = df.withColumn(
    "item",
    split(col("item"), ",").cast(ArrayType(IntegerType())).alias("item")
    )

df.printSchema()

df.show(2)

fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="item", minSupport=0.01, minConfidence=0.01)
model = fpGrowth.fit(df)
```

Below is the error i'm getting:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-74ec76b0ec20> in <module>
     14     df.printSchema()
     15 
---> 16     df.show(2)
     17 
     18     fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="item", minSupport=0.01, minConfidence=0.01)

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    378         """
    379         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    381         else:
    382             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o377.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 18, cluster-we8z-x-0.c.project_name.dataset_name, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConnectorUserAgentProvider
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation$.headerProvider(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:356)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation$.createReadClient(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:333)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$default$3$1.apply(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$default$3$1.apply(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.BigQueryRDD.compute(BigQueryRDD.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1892)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1880)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2113)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2051)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConnectorUserAgentProvider
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation$.headerProvider(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:356)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation$.createReadClient(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:333)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$default$3$1.apply(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$default$3$1.apply(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.BigQueryRDD.compute(BigQueryRDD.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also experienced this issue this morning. I was using the gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar when creating the DataProc cluster.

--properties spark:spark.jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar

This connector was update from 2.11 to 2.12 yesterday.

I had to down-graded down to the spark-bigquery-latest_2.11.jar connector to fix my scripts.

--properties spark:spark.jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.11.jar

The issue with the new 2.12 driver has been created on Github project: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/187

Comment: The connector had a new version yesterday, 0.16.0 that had introduced this bug (sorry about that). A bug fix version, 0.16.1, has been released.

Answer (score 1):

Please use version 0.16.1 and above of the spark-bigquery connector, available in `gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11-0.16.1.jar` and `gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.16.1.jar` (based on Spark's Scala version). It is also available from the maven central repository.